# HTML5 localstorage remember me in login box

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, local-storage

I have function which stores username and password in local storage once the remember me check box is clicked. So far it works fine, but the function only works when user enter his/her username and password in the input fields and then click on remember me check box.

So in short there are 2 cases:

1) Enter username and password -> click remember me check box -> submit form (works fine)
2) Click remember me check box -> Enter username and password -> submit form (Not working - Blank fields are displayed.)

How can I modify my function and make sure that if the user clicks on remember me check box first and then enter username and password the fields are populated on page refresh or when the user comes back to the website again.

This is my function looks like:

```
$(function() {

    if (localStorage.checkBoxValidation && localStorage.checkBoxValidation != '') {
        $('#rememberMe').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $('#loginEmail').val(localStorage.userName);
        $('#password').val(localStorage.password);
    } else {
        $('#rememberMe').removeAttr('checked');
        $('#loginEmail').val('');
        $('#password').val('');
    }

    $('#rememberMe').click(function() {

        if ($('#rememberMe').is(':checked')) {
            // save username and password
            localStorage.userName = $('#loginEmail').val();
            localStorage.password = $('#password').val();
            localStorage.checkBoxValidation = $('#rememberMe').val();
        } else {
            localStorage.userName = '';
            localStorage.password = '';
            localStorage.checkBoxValidation = '';
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't listen to the click events of specific form elements but rather to the submit event of the form.

When the form is submitted, you have the information from all fields at hand and the order in which the user fills in the form fields doesn't matter.

```
$('#my-form').on('submit', function() {
    /* place your logic here… */
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the data on form submit function

```
$('#urformid').on('submit', function() {

        if ($('#rememberMe').is(':checked')) {
            // save username and password
            localStorage.userName = $('#loginEmail').val();
            localStorage.password = $('#password').val();
            localStorage.checkBoxValidation = $('#rememberMe').val();
        } else {
            localStorage.userName = '';
            localStorage.password = '';
            localStorage.checkBoxValidation = '';
        }

        //Other form functions
});
```

Comment: @feela capture the keypress event and submit

Comment: Thank you both. I tried on both submit form and capturing keypress plus submit button click. It works either way. But I am going with using submit event on the form itself.

Comment: yeah that's why I accepted your response as the correct answer. Since there is no point firing 2 events.

Comment: @zaq i am not told capture in same function

Comment: @SridharR Yes I am aware of that and as mentioned in my first comment, I tried doing it in both ways and it works. However, can you tell me why your solution is better instead of saving values in local storage directly on form submit event. Since I am already taking care of keyboard 'enter' key event in the function where I am handling validation for my login form.

Comment: @zaq submit event is better same way we can do it like this way too.i dont know which is efficient and perfect :-(